# ServiceStack FileNotFoundException Deploying on IIS7

Tags: iis-7, servicestack

I developed a web service using ServiceStack (great framework, btw -- had fun using it) on .Net 3.5.  The service runs fine on the dev box under IIS6.  But when I try to deploy to a prod server running IIS7, I get the error:

> [FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'ServiceStack' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]

I tried deployment via both xcopy (which I thought was sufficient for ServiceStack) and MSDeploy -- same error.  The IIS7 virtual directory passes both authentication and authorization tests.

As mentioned, I'm not an IIS or ServiceStack expert.  Might this be a registration or GAC issue?  Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you check event log and give specific trace. It will tell which specific file or dll is missing or causing issue.